# Bizarre Manifestation of Inabilty to Wake from DPMS (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and amdgpu)

Tags: suspend, power-management, amdgpu

I've encountered a very strange problem with monitor sleep/wake (***not*** system suspend), which is similar to what I've seen discussed elsewhere, but mine seems a little unique.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (pretty fresh install), using an AMD Radeon RX 560 graphics card with the default ampgpu driver. I use an Acer monitor that's fairly new. First of all, here's what works:

- Everything while running Ubuntu
- System Suspend and wake

What doesn't work is dpms / blanking the screen (monitor sleep). When that happens, or when I force it with 'xset dpms force off', my GPU fan spins down to a slow speed and my monitor enters sleep. However, I can't wake it with key presses, mouse movement, or anything else! The only way I've found to resurrect video is to hard-reset the system with the reset button or power.

**First workaround: xset -dpms**

If I do this, the screen will not sleep, but will instead just go dark using Ubuntu's screen blanking function.

The problem is, I wasn't happy with that workaround as I don't want the screen always on, so I experimented and found another, strange workaround. **If I boot Ubuntu but leave dpms enabled, I can simply cycle my monitor power off/on (*after* boot). If I do that, the monitor will sleep (orange LED), but the GPU will stay fully "awake" with full fan speed and I can wake the monitor with a simple keypress or mouse movement.** This workaround continues to work until I reboot. The problem is, it's awkward to remember to cycle the monitor power after each boot!

Something is happening within Ubuntu or the amdgpu driver when I turn the monitor off/on, which doesn't occur if I simply boot with the monitor already powered up. Cycling power seems to force a DisplayPort handshake or something similar, which alters the behavior of GPU / monitor sleep in a way that allows wake from sleep.

What is it? Is the driver somehow altering the GPU's default sleep state when it recognizes the monitor? Perhaps the monitor is somehow non-responsive during the initial driver initialization, but responds more quickly after boot? I'm just speculating, I have no idea.

Can I work around this by simulating a monitor re-connection in a script, as part of every boot cycle? Can I solve the problem once and for all with some sort of setting change in X11, amdgpu, or elsewhere?

Thanks for any ideas / input!

Comment: Look at the logs. `sudo journalctl  -b 0` for system startup (includes monitor recognition and misconfiguration) and `sudo journalctl --since="-5 minutes"` after cycling monitor power. Find the differences.

Comment: @waltinator Any idea what to look for? The monitor power cycle log is short and unremarkable to my eyes. The boot log is quite long. What should I look for there? The monitor power cycle log doesn't precisely match the relevant boot log section, but I can't see anything problematic. Most noticeable is that the boot log is missing lines like this from the other log:
"gdm-x-session[2384]: (WW) AMDGPU(0): get vblank counter failed: Invalid argument"

Of course I have no idea how the presence of that sort of error could improve things.

Comment: Forgot to mention... at the point where the monitor power cycle log ends, the boot log does not. The very next line is this: "sleep.desktop[3555]: Warning: Only changing the first 20 of 10 buttons." That could be relevant I suppose?